# Optimized way of performing operations on dictionary of dataframes w.r.t. an aggregated dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, dictionary, optimization

I'm trying to compute the ratio of certain columns in all my dataframes(present as a dictionary) wrt an `aggregated_data`.

Here `data` is a dictionary and it contains the level name as key and its data(as dataframe) as values.

For eg:

1)This is how the data looks like(Just an example for illustration)

```
data={'State':State_data,'District':District_data}
>>> State_data
         Time  level value  97E03K  90KFTO  FXRDW9  1I4OX9  N6HO97
0  2017-04-01  State    NY      15       7       8      19      17
1  2017-05-01  State    NY      11       8       9      16      11
2  2017-06-01  State    NY      17      16       6      12      17
3  2017-04-01  State   WDC       6      17      19       8      20
4  2017-05-01  State   WDC      19       9      20      11      17
5  2017-06-01  State   WDC      10      11       6      20      11
>>> District_data
         Time     level     value  97E03K  90KFTO  FXRDW9  1I4OX9  N6HO97
0  2017-04-01  District  Downtown       2       1       5       3       5
1  2017-05-01  District  Downtown       4       3       2       4       3
2  2017-06-01  District  Downtown       4       3       4       1       3
3  2017-04-01  District   Central       3       4       3       5       5
4  2017-05-01  District   Central       4       3       5       4       3
5  2017-06-01  District   Central       4       3       5       5       3
```

2)This is how the aggregated data looks like:

```
         Time       level       value  97E03K  90KFTO  FXRDW9  1I4OX9  N6HO97
0  2017-04-01  Aggregated  Aggregated      27      21      23      30      21
1  2017-05-01  Aggregated  Aggregated      27      29      26      22      30
2  2017-06-01  Aggregated  Aggregated      27      30      30      25      25
3  2017-04-01  Aggregated  Aggregated      22      27      30      22      25
4  2017-05-01  Aggregated  Aggregated      22      21      24      22      29
5  2017-06-01  Aggregated  Aggregated      25      27      23      22      24
```

3. I've to iterate for each level and find the ratio of each level to the aggregated for the corresponding based on this dictionary:

`columns_to_work = {'97E03K': '97E03K', '90KFTO': '97E03K', 'FXRDW9': '97E03K', '1I4OX9': '1I4OX9', 'N6HO97': '97E03K'}`

Here for every key, I'll find the ratio of its value wrt to the aggregated level on the same date for the same value and replace the column name with the `key+'_rank'`.

Eg. For key `90KFTO`, the value `97E03K` at current level has to be divided wrt aggregated's `97E03K` column for the same timepoint. And this ratio is stored with key's name as `90KFTO_rank`.

Likewise, I'm finding for each level and appending each of it to a list which I'm finally concatenating to get a flat dataframe containing `'_rank'` columns for all inputted levels

4)Final output data looks something like this(Ratio of data wrt aggregated):

```
        Time     level     value  97E03K_rank  90KFTO_rank  FXRDW9_rank  1I4OX9_rank  N6HO97_rank
0   2017-04-01     State        NY     0.555556     0.555556     0.555556     0.633333     0.555556
1   2017-05-01     State        NY     0.407407     0.407407     0.407407     0.727273     0.407407
2   2017-06-01     State        NY     0.629630     0.629630     0.629630     0.480000     0.629630
3   2017-04-01     State       WDC     0.272727     0.272727     0.272727     0.363636     0.272727
4   2017-05-01     State       WDC     0.863636     0.863636     0.863636     0.500000     0.863636
5   2017-06-01     State       WDC     0.400000     0.400000     0.400000     0.909091     0.400000
6   2017-04-01  District  Downtown     0.074074     0.074074     0.074074     0.100000     0.074074
7   2017-05-01  District  Downtown     0.148148     0.148148     0.148148     0.181818     0.148148
8   2017-06-01  District  Downtown     0.148148     0.148148     0.148148     0.040000     0.148148
9   2017-04-01  District   Central     0.136364     0.136364     0.136364     0.227273     0.136364
10  2017-05-01  District   Central     0.181818     0.181818     0.181818     0.181818     0.181818
11  2017-06-01  District   Central     0.160000     0.160000     0.160000     0.227273     0.160000
```

***Now this is approach which needs to be optimized:***

```
samp_data=list()
level={}

for l,da in data.items(): #Here l is the key and da is the dataframe
    level[l] = da.copy()
    lev[l] = pd.DataFrame() #Just a copy to work with
    lev[l] = pd.concat([lev[l],level[l][[tim,'level','value']]],sort=False)
    
    for c,d in columns_to_work.items():
            
        level[l] = level[l].join(aggregated_data[[d]], on = tim, rsuffix = '_rank1')
        level[l].rename(columns = {d+'_rank1':c+'_rank'}, inplace=True)

        level[l][c+'_rank'] = level[l][d]/level[l][c+'_rank'] 
        lev[l] = pd.concat([lev[l],level[l][c+'_rank']],axis=1,sort=False)
        
    samp_data.append(lev[l])
```

****Explanation of Code if the logic is still not clear:****

In the first iteration, I'm iterating for all levels present in my dictionary and In the second iteration, I'm iterating over the column names. But here, the `columns_to_work is a dictionary with key and value both being columns in my dataframes.

I've to calculate the ratio of `d` column w.r.t the aggregated data for my current level and rename the column name with `c+"_rank"`.

Although the above code works fine for small datasets, it fails big time while trying to scale for bigger datasets. I'm looking for an optimized way of achieving the same. Any advice/suggestions will be greatly appreciated:)

P.S. I tried using the `aggregated_data` as a dictionary of lists to improve the performance. But the problem is some time points present in the `aggregated_data` file may not be in the `level` data. Hence the order mapping gets messed up.

Comment: Can you please add sample data? (both input and desired output)

Comment: Please check the updated question.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. I don't understand the logic used to create `aggregated_data`. can you please add that code?

Comment: Sure. The `aggregated_data` is available already..I'm not creating it.

Comment: Does `tim == 'Time'`?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've updated my question now. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

### Step 1: concat state and district data

```
df = pd.concat([State_data, District_data])
```

### Step 2: join sate and district data to aggregated data (using index, since there are multiple distinct rows for the same `Time`)

```
df = pd.merge(
    left=df,
    left_index=True, 
    right=aggregated_data.drop(columns=['level', 'value', 'Time']), 
    right_index=True,
    suffixes=['', '_agg']
)
```

### Step 3: Iterate through `columns_to_work`

```
for k, v in columns_to_work.items():
    df[f'{k}_rank'] = df[v]/df[f'{v}_agg']
```

### Step 4: Sort `df` and drop unnecessary columns

```
df = df[['Time', 'level', 'value', '97E03K_rank', '90KFTO_rank', 'FXRDW9_rank', '1I4OX9_rank', 'N6HO97_rank']].sort_values('level', ascending=False)
```

### End result:

```
       Time     level     value  97E03K_rank  90KFTO_rank  FXRDW9_rank  1I4OX9_rank  N6HO97_rank
 2017-04-01     State        NY        0.556        0.556        0.556        0.633        0.556
 2017-05-01     State        NY        0.407        0.407        0.407        0.727        0.407
 2017-06-01     State        NY        0.630        0.630        0.630        0.480        0.630
 2017-04-01     State       WDC        0.273        0.273        0.273        0.364        0.273
 2017-05-01     State       WDC        0.864        0.864        0.864        0.500        0.864
 2017-06-01     State       WDC        0.400        0.400        0.400        0.909        0.400
 2017-04-01  District  Downtown        0.074        0.074        0.074        0.100        0.074
 2017-05-01  District  Downtown        0.148        0.148        0.148        0.182        0.148
 2017-06-01  District  Downtown        0.148        0.148        0.148        0.040        0.148
 2017-04-01  District   Central        0.136        0.136        0.136        0.227        0.136
 2017-05-01  District   Central        0.182        0.182        0.182        0.182        0.182
 2017-06-01  District   Central        0.160        0.160        0.160        0.227        0.160
```

Comment: I forgot to update the question.I'm actually doing steps 1 and 2 in my solution. Your step 3 improved my code performance to a good extent. Thanks a lot for your response buddy!!